# Permanently deleting a git branch bitbucket

Tags: git

Is there any way to permanently delete a remote git branch, that can't be recovered by any means.
I'm working on a repository and want to delete branch in it, but I want it to be deleted in a way it should not be recovered. Its not a `master` branch. I just want to delete it permanently with no chance of recovering.

Comment: Note that if there are any merge commit merging that branch into any other branch that you want to keep then you'll have to keep **at least** the history of that branch up to the merge commit or you'll break your repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to delete a branch name (at least if you control the repository).  But Git is not really about *branches*, per se.  Git is all about *commits*.  To understand what it means to delete a *branch name*, you must understand how Git *finds* commits, and what Git does about *unreachable* commits.  Unreachable commits are—eventually!—garbage collected and discarded.  Reachable commits remain.  If a commit that has become unreachable is not immediately discarded, anyone can add a *new* name to make it reachable again, after which it will not be discarded.  And, of course, commits can be *copied* to other repositories, which can retain those commits as long as *they* want.

To delete a branch name in your own Git, use `git branch -d` or `git branch -D`.  The difference between these is that `-D` is a *forceful* delete: delete even if your Git says "that would make commits unreachable".  (In both cases, you *must not* have that particular branch checked out.  Git won't let you saw off the branch you're perched on.)

To send a delete request to some other Git, use `git push`:

```
git push <url-or-remote> :<name>
```

or:

```
git push --delete <url-or-remote> <name>
```

They may or may not obey this request to delete the name.

#### Long(ish)

Remember that every commit has its own, unique, big ugly hash ID.  That hash ID is universal across *every* Git: if you've created a new commit whose hash ID is `a123456...`, and I obtain that commit from your Git, I now have the commit whose hash ID is `a123456...`.  But hash IDs *look* totally random.<sup>1</sup>  How am I going to *remember* this ID?

There are two main "places" in which Git remembers commit hash IDs:

- First, every commit stores the raw hash ID of its immediate predecessor(s).  Git calls these the commit's *parents*.  Most commits have just one parent.  We say that the commit *points to* its parent, but in fact, the commit just has the actual hash ID of its predecessor as part of itself.
- Then—crucial for your question—a *branch name* simply stores the hash ID of the *last* commit in a chain of commits.  From this last commit, Git can find a parent hash ID.  Git can use that parent hash ID to find one earlier commit.  That earlier commit has a parent hash ID, which lets Git step back again, which provides another hash ID, which lets Git step back again, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit.

We can draw this.  If we use real hash IDs, it's messy, so we can use no name at all:

```
... ←●  ←●  ←●  ←●  ←branch
```

or substitute in single letters:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

What you get when you delete a branch *name* is this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

With no *name* by which to find the commit whose hash is `H`, we also have no way to find commit `G`, or commit `F`, or any of those earlier commits.

But maybe `branch` is not the *only* branch name that can find the commit.  For instance:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch
            \
             I--J   <-- branch2
```

Deleting the *name* `branch` is fine, but we can still start from the *name* `branch2` and find commit `J`, which lets us find `I`, which lets us find `H`.  So nothing happens to `H` after all, except that the *name* `branch` no longer points directly to commit `H`.

Besides this, *tags* also point to (single) commits, and there are other ways to name or find commits, such as via `git stash`, *remote-tracking* names (one Git's copy of some other Git's branch names), and so on.

All that removing a name does is take away that *one name*.  If that was the *only* way to find the commit, the commit still exists, but Git calls it *unreachable*.

If *you* have the hash ID stashed somewhere—written down on paper, or in a window on your screen, or whatever—you can still find the commit directly by its hash ID.  Suppose `branch2` points to a commit that *doesn't* point back to `H`, and that there are no other names for `H`:

```
          H   <-- branch
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- branch2
```

If you delete the *name* `branch`, commit `H` becomes unreachable, while commits through `G`, plus `I` and `J`, remain reachable through the name `branch2`.  But you have the hash ID `H` still on your screen, so now you grab it with the mouse and paste it into the command:

```
git branch resurrect <hash-of-H>
```

and you now have this:

```
          H   <-- resurrect
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- branch2
```

Your branch has been resurrected under a new name!

If you *don't* do this—if you delete the name `branch` and don't rescue the abandoned commit `H`, and no one else saves `H` before the Grim Collector `git gc` comes around and reaps it<sup>2</sup>—then, indeed, commit `H` vanishes entirely from this Git repository.  In the meantime, commit `H` is not *findable* and you won't *see* it unless you use its raw hash ID (or the raw hash ID of a *later* commit that reaches *back* to commit `H`).

But Git is *distributed*.  If I came along *before* you deleted all names by which `H` could be found, and snagged for myself a copy of `H` in *my* repository, and gave myself a name by which I can find `H`, your Git may delete `H` from *your* repository—eventually—but *I* will still have it.  I can give it to another Git, or send it back to your Git.

How quickly commits are GCed depends on many things.  If you delete a branch from a server Git, it tends to GC newly-unreachable commits pretty fast.  If you delete names from your own command-line-operated Git, it tends to GC them more slowly.<sup>3</sup>

If the reason you are getting rid of some commit(s) as found by a branch name is that they have leaked important security detail, you should consider that security compromised.  But if it's just that it is trash, well, delete away, and hope no one snagged copies of the trash and later pushes the trash back to you.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hash IDs are in fact not at all random: each one is a cryptographic checksum of the full contents of the underlying commit object.  That's *how* they are universal across every Git.  If I have your commit, I have it by the same checksum of its content.  If you have mine, you have it by *its* checksum.

<sup>2</sup>`git gc`, the Garbage Collector, serves as the grim reaper for commits, but actually consists of running a carefully sequenced series of lower-level commands.  These are what really get rid of unreachable commits.

<sup>3</sup>Your Git uses *reflogs* to contain extra, hidden, references to commit hash IDs.  Deleting a branch name currently also deletes that branch's reflog, but not the HEAD reflog, so the HEAD reflog may keep the commits alive for at least 30 days.  Server Git repositories generally don't have reflogs at all, which avoids the at-least-30-days preservation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

A branch is a logical entity, a pointer to a commit in history that's labelled for your convenience. Each commit then points to its parent, and following this hierarchy we get what most of us mean when we say "a branch".

You delete this on the remote via:

> git push remote_name :branch_name

If any of the commits on your branch have been merged into other branches (via fast-forward or merge commits) those will not be deleted, and can't be deleted unless you want to delete the other branches too. If there are any commits on the branch you deleted that have other "references" to them (i.e. tags), then these will not be deleted. Commits without references will eventually get deleted by the garbage collector.

However, if someone else has fetched the branch you are deleting to their local repo, they are free to check it out even after you delete it from the remote, and then push it again. This isn't the case if they've done `git remote prune remote_name` before checking it out.

This is the double-edged sword that a distributed source control system is.